# Snoop on Solaris, how to avoid "ether" packets?

Tags: networking, solaris

This filter works fine

```
snoop -vvx port 5858 and not port 22
```

But I see some "ether" headers

```
ETHER:  ----- Ether Header -----
ETHER:  
ETHER:  Packet 16 arrived at 13:01:37.43271
ETHER:  Packet size = 60 bytes
ETHER:  Destination = ***************,
ETHER:  Source = ***************,
ETHER:  Ethertype = 0800 (IP)
```

How to avoid ether?

On tcpdump i did this and work, how to obtain same result on snoop?

```
tcpdump -vvx -i net0 port 5858 and not stp
```

Comment: Remove `-vv`. You can also try `-V` (capital V), less info than -v.

Comment: On tcpdump, omitting the `-e` option is the reason link layer information such as Ethernet is not displayed.

Comment: Seeing that Oracle documents tcpdump, I guess it can be available from them? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E72487/tcpdump-8.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this line seems to solve

```
snoop -V -x host myhost and port 5858
```

As I understand -v put the protocols in order so is ETHER, then ip
then tcp (the output is incomplete, too long)

```
snoop -d net0 -v
Using device net0 (promiscuous mode)
ETHER:  ----- Ether Header -----
ETHER:  .........
ETHER:  Ethertype = 0800 (IP)
ETHER:  
IP:   ----- IP Header -----
IP:   
IP:   Version = 4
IP:   Header length = 20 bytes
IP:   Type of service = 0x48
IP:   .......
TCP:  ----- TCP Header -----
TCP:  
TCP:  Source port = 22
TCP:  Destination port = 55934 
TCP:  Sequence number = 52486020
TCP:  Acknowledgement number = 676130111
TCP:  Data offset = 20 bytes
TCP:  Flags = 0x18
TCP:        0... .... = No ECN congestion window reduced
TCP:        .0.. .... = No ECN echo
TCP:        ..0. .... = No urgent pointer
TCP:        ...1 .... = Acknowledgement
```